How to use dnsmasq to assign static IPs to hosts in multiple networks
We use dnsmasq to assign IPs to servers in our OKD cluster.  This worked fine as long as we were only assigning IPs within one network, but now we have a new group of servers that need to get IPs from a different network.  (Both networks are part of the same vlan, but we have to keep them separated, unfortunately.)  After some research, we came up with the following configuration:
port=0
interface=baremetal
bind-dynamic

dhcp-authoritative
dhcp-range=set:net24,69.xx.yy.0,static,255.255.255.0,3d
dhcp-range=set:net25,69.xx.zz.0,static,255.255.255.128,3d
dhcp-option=tag:net24,option:router,69.xx.yy.1
dhcp-option=tag:net25,option:router,69.xx.zz.1
dhcp-option=option:dns-server,8.8.8.8
dhcp-host=[mac 34],69.xx.yy.34,node034

[lots more hosts]

dhcp-host=[mac 13],69.xx.zz.13,lsl13

[a few more hosts]

But this doesn't work.  The log file says this when the process starts:
Jul 31 16:43:03 [url] dnsmasq-dhcp[284686]: DHCP, static leases only on 69.xx.yy.0, lease time 3d
Jul 31 16:43:03 [url] dnsmasq-dhcp[284686]: DHCP, static leases only on 69.xx.zz.0, lease time 3d

Which looks promising, but when one of the new hosts attempts to get its IP it says this:
Jul 31 16:43:05 [url] dnsmasq-dhcp[284686]: 1075202053 available DHCP subnet: 69.xx.yy.0/255.255.255.0
Jul 31 16:43:05 [url] dnsmasq-dhcp[284686]: 1075202053 DHCPDISCOVER(baremetal) [mac 13] no address available

At first we thought that the issue was that the baremetal interface is only on the first network, but we clearly see the DHCP requests arriving, so that seems to be ok.  Then we thought we were using the tags incorrectly, but we found several examples that looked very similar to what we have, so it doesn't seem like that's it either.  Does anybody know why dnsmasq registers that there are two networks initially but can only find one when it's time to assign the IPs?
thanks,
will

we clearly see the DHCP requests arriving what is in the requests? That's what usually determines what scope the client will be assigned.

Have you tried adding respective tag: to the dhcp-host= lines? (Actually, what you need might instead be set:...I admit that I'm just making some wild guesses here...)

Hi @GregAskew, as far as I can tell the request includes the name of the host and the MAC address, as shown in the excerpt from the log file I included.  Is there some way to see more of the request?  I already added log-debug, log-dhcp, and log-queries=extra to the config file.

Hi @TomYan, I tried adding the tag: to one of the dhcp-host lines but it didn't help.  As for set:, do you mean that the tag: should be set in dhcp-host line, rather than the dhcp-range line?

@user1118334 To be honest, I have no idea how the set/tag thing works exactly, but I did see the following line in the man page: Addresses allocated like this are not constrained to be in the range given by the --dhcp-range option, but they must be in the same subnet as some valid dhcp-range. So I wonder if you need to explicitly associate dhcp-host= lines to corresponding dhcp-range= lines. But because the dhcp-host= is probably the "entry point" when it is applicable, so I wonder if you should use set: in both dhcp-range= and dhcp-host= to get them "grouped"...

@user1118334 But I also wonder, if my "entry point" theory is correct, if you would need like set: in dhcp-host= and both set: and tag: in dhcp-range= (or perhaps even like both in both, so that when the dhcp-range= is the "entry point", it will be "aware of" the relevant dhcp-host= lines...?)

Well, after a certain amount of additional trial and error I managed to solve the problem: it turns out that dnsmasq needs an interface on both networks, even though the DHCP requests only have to come to one interface.  By adding a second ip, on the /25 network, to the baremetal interface, and then adding a second interface line to the config, I was able to get it to correctly assign IPs to hosts on the /25 network.  I guess dnsmasq has to be able to communicate with the host on the network that corresponds to the IP it wants to assign.

I thought you had two IPs on the interface. What do you mean by a second interface line though? Repeat interface=baremetal?

Apologies if that wasn't clear, there was only one IP on the interface.  I added a second one as an alias and then the line interface=baremetal:25.
